# How to sort SSRS Matrix report by Grand total field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I created a matrix report. The report looks like this:

[image]

I want to sort the output so the region with highest sales should come on top.

e.g. From the above report **South** should show on top then **West**, **Central** and **East**.

How can this be done in SSRS (2008R2)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should just need to change your sort expression in the Group Row properties. Should be something like

```
=Sum(Fields!YourFieldHere.Value)
```